# Will "bundle update" update all the gems on system or just the ones in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have cloned a rails app which is having Rails 5 along with some newer gems. Now I can't run it with "bundle" or "bundle install" as it is showing me a message to do "bundle update".

Since I have many running apps on my current system using older Rails 4 and older gems, I want to make sure bundle update don't mess other apps, current rails version, various gems and losing existing gems and configuration and uninstalling/rolling back can be time consuming.

Is it safe to run 'bundle update' without it affecting any other apps and gems ?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, no worries. Bundler only manages current project dependencies.

Comment: Is it true that bundler basically makes gemsets obsolete?  I couldn't find much documentation on it but when I dove in it seemed if using bundle you don't need to worry about gemsets.

Comment: @bkunzi01 yeah, absolutely. I don't use gemsets at all in my environment and don't know anyone who still does

Answer (score 1):

Use RVM for that

Url: (https://rvm.io/rvm/install)
if you are using rvm in that case you can easily switch to other ruby versions
and use **ruby version** and **ruby gemset**

RVM will manage different gems into different pockets(folders), so rubygems and their versions  are easy to manage

Ex:

> add name of project into .ruby-gemset file
>
> add version of ruby into .ruby-version file

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a different gemset for each project. That becomes cumbersome very quickly. Just use `.ruby-version` to specify the ruby version you want to use.

Comment: @ReggieB, we can use default gemset **global** for every project, but if we   use multiple project with same ruby version then it would become cumbersome. So it's good to have different gemset as well

Comment: If you use bundler - it will manage the gem dependencies on a project by project basis. That means in effect, the Gemfile.lock determines the gems loaded for a particular project. Using `.ruby-gemset` then becomes redundant - and you're just making your life a little more complicated by using it. Use bundler or gemsets - not both.

Answer (score 0):

This command will update all the gems mentioned in your gem file only.